# "Now {to, for} the next sentence"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

If I want to state a number of statements/sentences, and I have said the first one, then I want to say the next one, what would the correct preposition be that will indicate **moving from one sentence to the next one in the speech**?

I think both prepositions are valid, and each one has its own indication:

> Now **to** the next sentence.

I think it means *I now will move from the previous sentence to the next one.*

> Now **for** the next sentence.

This could mean *I now will get to the next sentence and talk about.*

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Now+for+the%2CNow+to+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNow%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNow%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0) (without any noun after "next", or else there wouldn't be any plot to show), both are used.

What I found in [my search](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Eys9bbInwFgC&pg=PT26&dq=now+to+the+next+statement&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwi9_lmL7iAhUCyqQKHWlFDBsQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=now%20to%20the%20next%20statement&f=false):

> Listen carefully now **to** this next statement.

I think "listen" is used implicitly in my examples, so would that make "to" the only possible, correct preposition for such structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Now for the next X,..." is a **very** common way to transition between discussing successive points, particularly in an essay or similar work. "listen" is not implied here. If "to" is to be used in such a construction, I would expect something like "now **as** to the next X..." or perhaps "Moving now to the next sentence, ..."

Consider also the very common introduction by a musician:

> Now, for my next selection I will play ....

or from a magician:

> Now, for my next trick, I will ....

The last of these is often used in an extended or metaphoric sense

> For his next trick, the Governor will try to ...

In short I do not think "Now to the next sentence." a favored form.